# What does this で in でいいですか do?

Tags: grammar, particle-で

アンドレアスさん、でいいですか？

"Are you well, Andreas?"

Obviously this で doesn't prevent me from understanding the sentence. 
However, what does it add to the sentence?

Comment: That’s actually not the correct understanding. Assuming the listener is Andreas, does this alternate punctuation help?「アンドレアスさん」でいいですか？

Comment: Ahhh, yeah that makes more sense :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This で is a sort of situation/method/means marker, and the sentence is confirming アンドレアスさん is the right name, choice, etc. "Is it okay if I used Andreas-san?" is a terrible translation but should help you understand the gist of the sentence.

For example, this is used in the following situations.

- You're seeing bad handwritten characters, and want someone to confirm if it really reads "Andreas".
- You're discussing with your boss who to hire, and you're about to conclude you will hire Andreas.
- Your team has a bothersome task, which you have to assign to someone. You're trying to ask Andreas if he can do it for the team.