# what does で in this sentence mean?

Tags: grammar

> あ、当日配る資料だけど、講演して頂く森先生に前に送ってもらったもの**で**いいか確認しておいてくれますか。

I am not sure もので is wether or not a compound noun,or でいいか is a compound noun,anyway,I can't understand it

Comment: Related/Dup? https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/54968/45489

Comment: You need to remember でいい as a fixed grammatical pattern. There are some good external articles about this: https://www.learn-japanese-adventure.com/japanese-particle-de.html / https://maggiesensei.com/2014/05/20/%E3%80%9C%E3%81%A7%E3%81%84%E3%81%84-%E3%80%9C%E3%81%A7%E3%82%82%E3%81%84%E3%81%84%E3%80%80vs%E3%80%80%E3%80%9C%E3%81%8C%E3%81%84%E3%81%84-de-ii-demo-ii-vs-ga-ii/

Comment: Just to be sure, the translation is "Can you check with the lecturer Mori-sensei if the materials he sent us previously are good enough (for the upcoming lecture)?" or more naturally, "Can you check with Mori-sensei if it's okay to reuse the materials he sent us before?"